# Change ItemsSource in the ViewModel with different collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone

I set a pivot itemsSource to a OservableCollection property in my ViewModel. When I click a button I want the pivots ItemSource to be bound to another property in the VM of type ObservableCollection. In the Xaml of the Page I set Pivots' ItemsSource once, and I know It is not a good approach to change it from the code-behind on the button click event, but rather only change the collection's content. The problem is the one is of Type1 and the other of Type2. How to do this in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

In your viewmodel you could have the list property be defined as an Object and bind to that, then in your command to switch the collections just set that object to your other list.

Here is a brief example

```
    private Object _list;
    private ObservableCollection<Int32> _intList;
    private ObservableCollection<String> _stringList;

    public Object List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("List");
        }
    }

    public void CommandExecuted()
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(_list, _intList))
        {
            List = _stringList;
        }
        else
        {
            List = _intList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not working. My ItemsSource cannot resolve this List (also list is a keyword..)

Comment: Can you update your first post with your code? I think you are setting the itemssource incorrectly or have the wrong binding syntax.

Answer (score -1):

If you keep the bound Item as an IEnumerable you should should be able to switch the collection and notify of the switch.
        private IEnumerable _boundList;
        private ObservableCollection _firstCollection;
        private ObservableCollection _SecondCollection;

```
    public IEnumerable BoundList
    {
        get { return _boundList; }
        set
        {
            _boundList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BoundList");
        }
    }

    public void CommandExecuted()
    {
        BoundList = _boundList == _firstCollection ? (IEnumerable)_SecondCollection : _firstCollection;
    }
```

Comment: It tells me that cannot resolve the resource: WinRT information: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key BoundList. Also in the CommandExecuted "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>' and 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<int>'
"

Comment: I updated the CommandExecute to work. The above code should work and I have tested it. If you are getting some other issue post your xaml. When I see thing like Can not find resource, that tends to point to xamle expecting a resource to be present and it is not.